# Wi-fi drivers on old laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I have a LG R590-P.BE54P1, which was not on use, so I decided to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS on it. However, I can find wi-fi networks but can't connect to them. I've searched for similar problems but wasn't able to solve it. Can anybody help me?

Based on similar question, I executed the command shown below, in case it is relevant.

[image: Screenshot]

As requested, here is the result of sudo dmesg | grep  -i rtl:
https://pastebin.com/jp01Yr8B

As requested, here is the result of running wireless-info: https://pastebin.com/bQEuRdrw

Comment: You have a working driver, rtl8192se. Let's find out why it isn't working. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep  -i rtl`

Comment: Just did it as requested

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Will do the checks described

Comment: Added the info provided by the wireless-info script

Comment: You are trying and failing to connect to: `CARVALHO 2  <MAC 'CARVALHO 2' [AN2]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  130 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no`  With a signal strength of 14, I doubt that either of the antenna connectors are firmly connected. Please check: https://callnerds.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/wireless-adapter-1024x722.jpg

Comment: Thank you will take a look at that

Comment: There was an unconnected cable at the wifi antenna, I connected it and it is now working. Thank you all for the help